# JavaFX Task returning Map needs too much time

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

I have JFX Task which is receiving a HashMap from the Server. This operation does take around 5 seconds then I return this Map to get the data in the OnSucceeded EventHandler this does take around one minute until the Application enters the OnSucceeded EventHandler.

Anyone knows why it does take so long until the return value is reaching the Eventhandler?

Additional I tried to return null but it still does take so long. However, if i comment in the business line the Task is running normal.

```
 Task<HashMap<Long, PCSortArticle>> taskO = new Task<HashMap<Long, PCSortArticle>>() {
        @Override
        protected HashMap<Long, PCSortArticle> call() throws Exception {
              log.debug("start task loading article");
              log.debug("requesting articles from server");
              HashMap<Long, PCSortArticle> articles = business.getArticlesForCatalogLevel(treeKeyHolder.getSelectedTreeKey(true));
              log.debug("got articles from server");
              return articles;

        }
    };
    taskO.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            log.debug("start building tableview articles");
        }
    });
    new Thread(taskO).start();
```

Edit: 
I added some log

2016-03-10 17:05:42,835 DEBUGstart task loading article

2016-03-10 17:05:42,836 DEBUG  requesting articles from server

2016-03-10 17:05:44,877 DEBUG got articles from server

2016-03-10 17:06:39,179 DEBUG  start building tableview articles

Comment: Can you clarify what is taking the time? If it's the actual execution of `business.getArticlesForCatalogLevel(...)` then no-one can really answer that without knowing what that method does. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include the log output?

Comment: Like I said the business call does take 5 seconds this is not the problem. The return command does take so long. I tried to debug into the task code but when Im debugging i cant finde the problem because it takes too long. When I go through every line and reach the end I directly jump into the success EventHandler.I added some log to my post.

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if your FX Application Thread is too busy to get to the `onSucceeded` handler. Are you submitting any runnables via `Platform.runLater(...)` from `business.getArticlesForCatalogLevel()`?

Comment: The method does only do a remote call to the server and returns the value. It looks like : `Result result = remote.getData(params); return result;`

Comment: If you replace the content of `business.getArticlesForCatalogLevel()` with just a mock implementation (i.e. do `Thread.sleep(5000);` and then return some hard-coded data), what happens?

Comment: When i remove the business line the task is running  normal. Thats what i dont understand it seems like the remote call is not complete finished but when i log the map size it seems to be completed.

Comment: That's why I suggested replacing the *implementation* of the business method with a mock implementation. The only real way to get help solving this is to create a reproducible [MCVE].

Comment: I will do tomorrow but it is home time now.